# Can't proxy dependency in the Eclipse Paho repository through Nexus

Tags: nexus

I've added https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/ as a proxy repository in Nexus and added it to the public group. Nexus blocked it as an untrusted remote, so I disabled auto-blocking. However, I can't download `org.eclipse.paho:mqtt-client:0.4.0`, which is available there. And when I open `Browse Remote` tab for this repository, the tree is empty. Is it necessary to add the SSL certificate despite disabling auto-blocking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you access the repository via https you need to register the certificate. If you are using Nexus OSS you have to do that in the JVM running Nexus. With Nexus Professional you can do that in the SSL user interface. Detailed documentation is [in the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl.html).